# ASP.NET Core OAuth with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I have two questions, really. I'm learning authorization in ASP.NET Core using the OAuth scheme for my company's authority. The thing is, on the final (3rd) leg, requesting a token, I need to authenticate the client (client id/client secret) using basic authentication (as per RFC 6749/2.3.1) but from what I have seen from the traffic client credentials are sent in the body instead.

I have a very hard time finding good documentation on the `AuthenticstionBuilder.AddOAuth` extension method so my first question is for tips where I might find a proper walkthrough that explains how to use the options and the four events supported? What I have found is people explaining how to set it up for this or that authority (such as GitHub, Facebook etc.) but none explains how the scheme implementation is designed. As a last resort I will have to check out the source code but if anyone can provide some links to a good explanatory walkthrough I would really appreciate it.

My second question is if there is a way to use Basic Auth for obtaining the token, as I describe above? I assumed there would have been an event where I could do that but my experiments indicates the three available events aren't suited for this.

Comment: You could check the [OAuthExtensions.AddOAuth Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.oauthextensions.addoauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to learn more about the AddOauth method, and if you want to check the source, check [this github link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth).

Comment: That's what I've done. That extension authenticates the client with credentials in the body, not with Basic Authentication.  As far as I can tell it also doesn't support hooking into the event for fetching the token from the token issuer.

Comment: You typically dont use AddOAuth for new development, use AddOpenIDConnect instead.